# Is there a way to pass a nan value as null from a Pandas dataframe to a table in an Oracle database using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, plsql, sqlalchemy

I am attempting to merge values from a pandas dataframe into a table within an Oracle database using SQLAlchemy. The table has 137 columns, and some entries within the columns contain no value (represented by null in Oracle). Is there a way to enter no value (None/null) using sqlalchemy without the values being changed to CLOB within the database? I will be working with many large tables with different column specifications, so it would be good to find a generic way of doing this.

When I assign the numpy nan value, I get the following error: 
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-00910: specified length too long for its datatype

The columns have been specified within the database with a variety of different precisions (some are only 1 character). Therefore entering 'nan' into some table cells will not work.

I have a dataframe, df, of dimensions n rows x 137 columns.
I have tried filling in the empty values with:

```py
df.fillna(np.nan,inplace=True)
```

To specify the datatypes I use:

```
dtypes1 = {c:types.VARCHAR(df[c].str.len().max()) for c in df.columns[df.dtypes == 'object'].tolist()}
```

And then the following statement to transfer the table to a temporary table within Oracle (this works fine):

```
df.to_sql('table1', conn2, if_exists='replace', dtype=dtypes1, index=false)
```

I then attempt to merge the data from table1 to the original table, table2 by:

1. creating a connection to the Oracle db using an SQLAlchemy engine:

```
conn = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://.......')
```

2. Defining the merge statement:

```
SQL_statement = 'MERGE INTO '  + table2 + ' USING ' + table1 + ' ON (' + table1 + '.TIME = ' + table2 + '.TIME AND ' + table1 + '.ID = ' + table2 + '.ID) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ' + updateMsg + ' WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (' + insertMsgB + ') VALUES (' + insertMsgA + ')'
```

3. executing the merge statement

```
conn.execute(SQL_statement)
```

I would like no value (null) to be entered within the table when the table changes are merged into the original Oracle table.

At the moment, I think my code is trying to write 'nan' into the cells, but this doesn't conform with the column specifications.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: SGeo welcome to So. Please review the help section [ask]. For this the DDL and which specific columns you're having problems may be useful.  You indicate a column with no value is  "represented by None in Oracle". If so this in your design definition not Oracle's. The standard Oracle defined no value is NULL. As long as the column is not a primary key (PK) or declared as NOT NULL, or otherwise constrained NULL is valid for any column definition. You may want to translate your values "None" and "nan' to null.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Belayer. You are quite right about using null, and I have edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: I've also found a work-around by merging only the columns that have been edited to include data, but it would still be good to know how to specify null values, so that whole rows can be added without some column datatypes being defined as CLOB.